# Material UI Chip-input's "hintText" is not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a [ChipInput](https://github.com/TeamWertarbyte/material-ui-chip-input) like this. I want to show a hint text when it's empty.

```
<div className={classes.headline}>
     <ChipInput
          hintText='Type anything'
          onChange={this.handleTagChange}
     />
</div>
```

But my browser gives this warning.

> Warning: React does not recognize the `hintText` prop on a DOM
>   element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom
>   attribute, spell it as lowercase `hinttext` instead. If you
>   accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM
>   element.

As per the [ChipInput Readme](https://github.com/TeamWertarbyte/material-ui-chip-input), it should work. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Had a look at the code and found `placeholder` which worked!!!

```
<div className={classes.headline}>
     <ChipInput
          placeholder='Type anything'
          onChange={this.handleTagChange}
     />
</div>
```